# How to show Google map with kml file in unity3d

Tags: google-maps, kml, unity-game-engine

I want to draw few polygons on top of google map based on [kml](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) file. These polygons should be clickable. I know how to do all this in javascript and on website but i am new in Unity3d and i did not find any component which display google map in unity. Any help would be hight appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firs two results on Google with the search: "unity3d how to display google map"

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19263/embed-google-maps-into-unity-3d.html

↓ this looks awesome, dont know if it works tho
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3573

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 2nd solution need a asset which is depending upon another paid asset which has a high cost. In case of 1st solution, My application is for android not for web. Another thing is that i need to draw polygon from kml file and not just static kind of map. Please do let me know if you have another solution for it.

Comment: On the second link, you said it needs the paid asset, are you talking about "UniWeb" ? Because it works without it, scroll down the page and read the comments, some guys made it work without the plugin.
Also you have it for free : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/40505
Let me know if it helped.

Comment: yes same thing!! Another thing, will it work for Android device. I have forgot to mention that i am doing all this for Android application.

Comment: Can you have a look at my another question also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645666/how-to-get-click-element-of-svg-image-in-unity3d

Comment: I have no idea if it will work for android, as its the first time i see this plugin, never used it. As for your second question i really dont know, i have never done anything like that before.Wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do You need google maps or can You use open street map or bing? If yes then try  this asset https://github.com/jderrough/UnitySlippyMap - its free and workds on all platforms ( I used it on pc, mac, ios, android, windows phone)

As form kml files its trickier the only solution I found was to read kml file like xml and generate line renderers or meshes from polygons with code.